# Retrieve WordPress photos' values to place in a custom php page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I need to create a WordPress website out of already available HTML (more specifically out of an asp.net website), so I'm creating a template & using the following method to target php pages:

```
 <?php
 /*
 Template Name: students
 */
 ?>
```

**My Question**: How to **insert images in WordPress CMS\dashboard** & how to **retrieve their values (only the images' values)**. Here is a static example:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 img-grids mt-lg-0 mt-5 pl-lg-4">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/p1.jpg'; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid radius-image" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/p2.jpg'; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid radius-image" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/p3.jpg'; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid radius-image" />
</div>
```

**But above would work if the website was static, but I need the images to be manageable from backend**. Dynamic images that change.

**Thought 1**:

1. I uploaded photos in a WordPress Gallery in a Post.
2. But then `<?php the_content(); ?>` shows an ugly gallery as is & not just the images' values.

**Thought 2**:

1. In functions.php I can try to create a **shortcode** or a php function to retrieve gallery values of a specific post ID, but then this post could get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can first create a metabox that inserts images into a page, then insert the metabox values ​​into your code.
In this way, every time you change the images in the meta box of your page, it also changes on the user side. A general example (WooCommerce Image Gallery)

My suggestion is to use the acf plugin, but there is also a free version that you can download from [this link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

And you can also use [this link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/) to create a gallery

Of course you can code all of this
But I suggest using this plugin.

Comment: I'll have to look into these & get back you. But do you have an example on Metabox for Images?

Comment: Hi yes I have added several metabox samples before. Just to be sure.
You want to display some dynamic images on one page of your site.
So I will create and send a metabox for you.

Comment: it would be great from you. I created a new question showing you what I tried, Metabox at CMS is ok but I don't know how to retrieve the values at the frontend. Here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463395/retrieve-photogallery-image-values-at-frontend-of-a-wordpress-meta-box

Comment: @compliance Hello
I have your answer on the same page and I am really excited to introduce an attractive plugin