# Retrieve photogallery image values at frontend, of a WordPress Meta Box

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, meta-boxes

**Summary**:

I need to use my own html photogallery so to do this:

- I was advised to use MetaBox so I found & installed **MetaBox.io plugin**.
- Next I generated an **Advanced Image** code using their website & added it at functions.php for it to show the uploader at Backend.
- But at Front-end I'm having trouble to retrieve the images' values.

**Functions.php** (MetaBox.io generated code):

```php
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'your_prefix_register_meta_boxes' );

function your_prefix_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = '';

    $meta_boxes[] = [
        'title'   => esc_html__( 'Untitled Field Group', 'online-generator' ),
        'id'      => 'untitled',
        'context' => 'normal',
        'fields'  => [
            [
                'type'             => 'image_advanced',
                'name'             => esc_html__( 'Image Advanced', 'online-generator' ),
                'id'               => $prefix . 'image_advanced_8hswqfsoqai',
                'max_file_uploads' => 40,
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

**CMS**:

Here's the result at CMS. A new images field is created. CMS part is done:

[image]

**Frontend**:

Then I grabbed this code from MetaBox.io & placed it at index.php **but it prints nothing**:

```php
<?php
$images = rwmb_meta( $field_id, array( 'size' => 'thumbnail' ) );
foreach ( $images as $image ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$image['full_url'].'"><img src="'.$image['url'].'"></a>';
}
?>
```

---

**My question is**:

How to display the MetaBox.io plugin images' values at frontend (inside my own HTML)? I need them as follows:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 img-grids mt-lg-0 mt-5 pl-lg-4">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/p1.jpg'; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid radius-image" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/p2.jpg'; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid radius-image" />
</div>
```

Note: the main reason I didn't simply add a gallery inside the post content but had to add a gallery as a Meta Box, is because I don't need the gallery to show as is , but to retrieve the gallery individual values at frontend inside my own html code.

Comment: `$images = rwmb_meta( $field_id, ...` - and `$field_id` contains the correct value at this point?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your valuable question. To answer your question it throws error " Undefined variable $field_id". Please bear with me I'm new to WordPress so I was trying all codes from their website but the thing is i'm not sure where to place this code in index.php as documentation isn't very clear :( Do you know a native method with wordpress for metabox backend & cms?

Comment: I would guess that you simply have to provide the same field ID, as you used when you registered the field ...? `$images = rwmb_meta( 'image_advanced_8hswqfsoqai', array( 'size' => 'thumbnail' ) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for following my advice
So here we are

```
$images = rwmb_meta ($field_id, array ('size' => 'thumbnail'));
```

We have the amount that our gallery receives.

According to the above codes, use this code inside the page template file or inside the loop.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 img-grids mt-lg-0 mt-5 pl-lg-4">

<?php

$untitled_meta = rwmb_meta('image_advanced_8hswqfsoqai' , '' , get_the_ID());

foreach ($untitled_meta as $image) {
    ?>

    <img src="<?= $image['full_url'] // Or Use url for crop size  ?>" alt="<?= $image['alt'] ?>"
         class="img-fluid radius-image"/>

    <?php
}
?>
```

The `rwmb_meta` function has three arguments.

1. The first value of our field ID that is fielded according to your
   code structure: `image_advanced_8hswqfsoqai`
2. And leave the next value blank to receive all.
3. And the last parameter is the page ID or post that I got with the
   `get_the_ID()` ID of the page we are in now.

To optimize and use the page according to your previous question on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444811/retrieve-wordpress-photos-values-to-place-in-a-custom-html-page/72446616?noredirect=1#comment128010018_72446616), I write the following code and please paste it (of course, if you want to work with the page template)

**Step 1: Add a function to build the meta box on the page and post**

Put this code in the `functions.php` file as you know it

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'compliance_students_gallery_meta_boxes' );

function compliance_students_gallery_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {

    $meta_boxes[] = [
        'title'   => esc_html__( 'Untitled Field Group', 'online-generator' ),
        'id'      => 'untitled',
        'context' => 'normal',
        'post_types' => ['post', 'page'],
        'fields'  => [
            [
                'type'             => 'image_advanced',
                'name'             => esc_html__( 'Image Advanced', 'online-generator' ),
                'id'               => 'images_untitled',
                'max_file_uploads' => 40,
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

Now you can add an image gallery to both the page and the post

**Step 2: Display in the page template the same file that contains this `Template Name: students` Of course, this is only for you who asked the relevant question elsewhere ([this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444811/retrieve-wordpress-photos-values-to-place-in-a-custom-html-page/72446616?noredirect=1#comment128010018_72446616))**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 img-grids mt-lg-0 mt-5 pl-lg-4">

    <?php

    $untitled_meta = rwmb_meta('image_advanced_8hswqfsoqai' , '' , get_the_ID());

    foreach ($untitled_meta as $image) {
        ?>

        <img src="<?= $image['full_url'] // Or Use url for crop size  ?>" alt="<?= $image['alt'] ?>"
             class="img-fluid radius-image"/>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

***Important note***
This should be the case if you want to show inside the circle or the main page or inside the posts.

To display the amount of image or any other liquid, you must use it in the WordPress query.

Example for use in a WordPress query loop

```
<?php

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    // some code here if you want.
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-6 img-grids mt-lg-0 mt-5 pl-lg-4">

            <?php

            $untitled_meta = rwmb_meta('image_advanced_8hswqfsoqai', '', get_the_ID());

            foreach ($untitled_meta as $image) {
                ?>
                <img src="<?= $image['full_url'] // Or Use url for crop size   ?>" alt="<?= $image['alt'] ?>"
                     class="img-fluid radius-image"/>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please I have a 2nd issue, after your answer i'll mark this as answer. I'm required to do add custom fields to the Media Gallery, how to do so backend & frontend? I edited my question & posted a screenshot for you.

Comment: So please can you help on my 2nd issue? By the way you're a godsend Morteza the query loop is what I needed & let me explain why. I will need to retrieve the images in a php page type & not a post. Meaning, `get_the_ID()` would be empty without the query loop when i'm not in a post. Good job on the full example.

Comment: Hello
Thanks for the explanation, I will definitely explain the second issue, but I am busy now and I will send you a message as soon as it is over.
As for the page item, it works even if it is not inside the loop, because if it is not a loop, WordPress will automatically return the ID of the page it first finds. Anyway, I will explain about this.

Comment: yes Morteza :) get_the_ID() works in a page, but I have special case where I inserted the gallery not in a PAGE but **in a POST belonging to a category** which in turn I retrieve in a page thus your full example was a lifesaver so I had to get posts of a category by adding this at the top of your code `$args = array('cat' => 8);`. Please don't forget my last issue on how to add & retrieve new fields for the Media Gallery images.

Comment: I created a new Question on how to add & retrieve custom fields values for Media Library images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528294/how-to-retrieve-at-frontend-the-values-of-wordpress-custom-fields-created-for-me

Comment: @compliance Hello, if you have not found an answer yet, I will have free time in the next two days and I can do this.