# How to retrieve at Frontend the values of WordPress custom fields created for Media Library Images (Full example included)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have 2 different working methods at functions.php **for backend**. Each method below has 2 hooks; **1 to display the new custom field & another hook to save\update the values**:

**Method 1**:

```
function media_hacks_attachment_field_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ){
    // https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata
    $media_author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'media_author', true );
    
    $form_fields['media_author'] = array(
        'value' => $media_author ? $media_author : '',
        'label' => __( 'Author' )
    ); 
    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'media_hacks_attachment_field_to_edit', null, 2 );

//Saving value on Update (method 1)
function media_hacks_edit_attachment( $attachment_id ){
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['media_author'] ) ) {
    
        $media_author = $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['media_author'];
    
        update_post_meta( $attachment_id, 'media_author', $media_author );
    }
}
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'media_hacks_edit_attachment' );
```

**Method 2**:

```php
function my_image_attachment_fields_to_edit($form_fields, $post) {
    // $form_fields is a special array of fields to include in the attachment form
    // $post is the attachment record in the database
    //     $post->post_type == 'attachment'
    // (attachments are treated as posts in Wordpress)
     
    // add our custom field to the $form_fields array
    // input type="text" name/id="attachments[$attachment->ID][custom1]"
    $form_fields["custom1"] = array(
        "label" => __("Custom Text Field"),
        "input" => "text", // this is default if "input" is omitted
        "value" => get_post_meta($post->ID, "_custom1", true)
    );
    // if you will be adding error messages for your field, 
    // then in order to not overwrite them, as they are pre-attached 
    // to this array, you would need to set the field up like this:
    $form_fields["custom1"]["label"] = __("Custom Text Field");
    $form_fields["custom1"]["input"] = "text";
    $form_fields["custom1"]["value"] = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_custom1", true);
     
    return $form_fields;
}
// attach our function to the correct hook
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "my_image_attachment_fields_to_edit", null, 2);

//Saving value on Update (method 2)
function my_image_attachment_fields_to_save($post, $attachment) {
    // $attachment part of the form $_POST ($_POST[attachments][postID])
    // $post attachments wp post array - will be saved after returned
    //     $post['post_type'] == 'attachment'
    if( isset($attachment['custom1']) ){
        // update_post_meta(postID, meta_key, meta_value);
        update_post_meta($post['ID'], '_custom1', $attachment['custom1']);
    }
    return $post;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "my_image_attachment_fields_to_save", null, 2);
```

**Here's the good result at backend Media Library** (Custom Text Field & Author):

[image]

This was it for the **Backend dashboard**.

---

**My question is for the Frontend**:

Now **how can I retrieve & display values of these 2 custom fields at the FRONTEND**?

Here's my failed try at a template php page:

```
<tr id='MySpecialRow'>
    <td colspan='2' style='background:#000;color:#fff;'>
      <?php

        $args = array('cat' => 8);

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($query->have_posts()) {
          // some code here if you want.
          while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();

            $untitled_meta = rwmb_meta('image_advanced_8hswqfsoqai', '', get_the_ID());
            foreach ($untitled_meta as $image) {

              $media_author = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'media_author', true );
              echo get_the_ID();//correctly prints post id
              echo $media_author;//prints nothing :(

            }
          }
        }
      ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Small notes:

- `get_the_ID()` does print the post id, but `$media_author` has no value :(
- I'm doing a WordPress posts query loop because the gallery containing the custom fields exists in a Post. In other words I don't have the post Id since I'm at a Page template.

Comment: `foreach ($untitled_meta as $image)` - what is `$untitled_meta` supposed to be here? And shouldn't you presumably be using the ID of `$image` here then to fetch the meta data? It is stored on the media item post after all, is it not?

Comment: @CBroe yes sorry i forgot to paste `$untitled_meta` line. Ok so with the 1st `get_the_ID()` I have the correct post ids in a loop so how to get the media images ids?

Comment: That still doesn't tell us what exactly you have stored in that meta field to begin with. What is `$image` now? Image ID as an integer? A complex object? ...?

Comment: @CBroe if I do `var_dump($untitled_meta);` I get the Media Library images which are in an advanced gallery (i'm using MetaBox) existing in a post. So `$image` is 1 image from this gallery. Thanks for your question dear.

Comment: _"I get the Media Library images"_ - meaning what, _exactly_? Do you get PHP objects/arrays, do you get HTML code that would display those images ...?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks again. As I see it, `$untitled_meta` contains an array with all the images as objects. But with your help now I see that `$untitled_meta` doesn't have the custom fields which I need to retrieve :O

Comment: _"an array with all the images as objects"_ - then those objects presumably have an ID property, so use that ...

Comment: @CBroe Yes :) in the array I can see [87] and [88] as the image IDs. And i tried static values like this `$media_author = get_post_meta( 88, 'media_author', true );` Notice 88 here & I do get the custom field values correctly. I'll do a research to see how to get the ID in the foreach loop. Like this it will be solved. Got any code?

Comment: Well just `$image->ID` should do it then? (Or _just_ `$image`, if this is a plain array of IDs, instead of actual image post objects.)

Comment: Thanks dear but `$image` & `$image->ID` both fail with error "Attempt to read property ID on array". Here's the array: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEqSc.jpg

Comment: It's the array keys holding the ID, so you need to use the extended foreach syntax: `foreach ($untitled_meta as $id => $image)`

Comment: YES! this is the correct answer. And now in `$media_author` line I just use `$id`. Please can you post your correction as answer? So my code has 2 modified lines. Oh and please can you explain a bit the extended foreach syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you got has the image post object ID as the array keys, so you need to use the extended foreach syntax to get access to the key as well.

```
foreach ($untitled_meta as $id => $image) {
  $media_author = get_post_meta( $id, 'media_author', true );
```

Normally when looping over array data you rather seldom need access to the key as well, but when you do, PHP offers the `$key => $value` syntax to get access to the key as well, https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I previously created a somewhat related question. It was how to create a gallery as MetaBox & retrieve its values at Frontend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463395/retrieve-photogallery-image-values-at-frontend-of-a-wordpress-meta-box